# ActorConcurrencyLockTimeoutException on actors that aggregate state in a building hierarchy

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a service fabric service that reads sensor messages off of a RabbitMQ queue. It then calls into a sensor actor with the message content so the sensor actor can update it's state.  The sensor actor then calls a room actor so that it can update it's state and the processes continues to floor, building, site.

I occasionally we get a ActorConcurrencyLockTimeoutException on a room, floor or building actor and the message queues start to back up.  Is there another design pattern that I could have used to avoid this concurrency issue?

Comment: This is a known behavior i think based on the following research paper on Virtual Actor pattern on which reliable actor is based. "If the actor is busy processing a previous invocation, the
request is queued until that request’s execution is
completed" .https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Orleans-MSR-TR-2014-41.pdf

Comment: Some other patterns if you like to refer. https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-patterns-introduction.md

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking at the other patterns at https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-patterns-introduction.md  However, I cannot seem to wrap my head around how I would change my design to use another pattern, such as the Distributed Computation pattern, which based on a comment in the anti-patterns section states that this pattern might be of benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by Actor calling Actor, calling Actor (etc). During this call, all Actors remain locked during execution (single entry). If one of the actors in the chain takes longer to process a message the entire chain (upwards) is slowed down.

You can cut the dependencies between Actors by using an Event Driven architecture. By simply publishing changes to a broker and not waiting for processing, you reduce the dependency chain to one (the broker).
An oss example of a pub-sub approach can be found [here](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors). Also available on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/).

Comment: Thank you, that is what I expected was causing the issues.  I took a look at the oss and I have a quick question.  Does each broker actor only handle a single message type?  So, if I have 5 message types I would need 5 broker actors.

Comment: Every message type results in 1 BrokerActor instance. However, I recommend using the broker service instead of the broker actor. One broker service (x replicas) can be used for all message types.

Comment: Is there a way to pass in or configure a JsonConverter that can be used to assist Json.NET with message deserialization?  Some of my messages currently require this. Thanks

Comment: Yes, type `MessageWrapper` has a static property you can set at launch time, using a custom implementation of `IPayloadSerializer`. (The default implementation `DefaultPayloadSerializer` uses Json.NET). Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does.  I will give it a try.  Thanks again.